# How to install and configure the EclipseFP Haskell plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, haskell, eclipse-plugin

Can somone who has done this tell me exactly what to do? The documentation is lacking and what is there is incomplete and incorrect.

I've got the plugin installed, and told it to usethe GHC installation that I have as part of the Haskell Platform but Run As.. only shows me Run GHCi session.  According to the cheat sheet, I should see Haskell Application.

Also missing are instructions for where to find the hugs executable, and the Cabal installation that the Haskell Preferences seems to suggest I should have.

Can anyone point out what I've missed?

I'm a Haskell beginner, hence trying to get Eclipse set up so I can play with it...

Comment: Maybe you will only see "Run Haskell Application" if you are using the project builder? Its a long time since I used EclipseFP but it seemed to like building executables in a particular way - adding lots of config files and installing into the project's "bin" directory. As for Hugs, it is now rather old. Unless you are working from a text book that specifically uses Hugs, its preferable to use GHCi instead. GHCi is a interactive top level (REPL) for GHC and has much of the same functionality as Hugs has.

Comment: Thanks. I did add a new project so I would have thought I'd end up using the builder (and I followed the instructions in the cheat sheet, as closely as possible given they're just not applicable in several cases - this may be because they've not been updated for newer versions of Eclipse?). Hugs might be old but if so the plugin/instructions should be updated, ideally.

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but you might be interested in looking at this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220638/haskell-hello-world-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that currently there is no way to create a non-interactive launch configuration
via GUI. However, you can do that by manually editing config files. The following instructions work with Eclipse 3.5.2, EclipseFP 2.0.2:

1. Make sure there exists a GHCI configuration.
2. Close Eclipse.
3. Go to directory .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/launches in the root of your workspace.
4. There should be a file named something like "Main (project src).launch". Copy it under whatever name you wish, for instance "Run Main.launch"
5. Open your copied file in a text editor and replace the option `--interactive` with `-e main`.
6. Save the file and start eclipse. You should see the new run configuration "Run Main". When you run it, EclipseFP executes your Main.hs file, redirecting both input and output to the console view.

Also, it seems that you haven't configured cabal yet. You first need to install it (from your distribution repositories, or [here](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html) if you're using Windows). Then go to Scion and Cabal preferences and point them to your cabal executable. After you click OK the compilation of Scion should start. If it gives you errors, read what packages are missing and install them via `cabal install pkg-name`. (I had to install happy with --global flag, and for QuickCheck I had to manually set the 2.* version). To rerun Scion compilation, restart Eclipse.